# Convert a 'for' loop into a matrix expression?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I need to convert a `for` loop in an expression using matrices form. I have a matrix `C`:

Matrix `C`:

```
    array([[0, 1, 1],
           [1, 0, 0],
           [1, 0, 0]])
```

A vector `delta_E`:

```
    array([ 4.,  2.,  4.,  1.])
```

`A` is a matrix of of zeros with the dimension of `C`, a vector `E` of length 3, and a list of `indices`:

```
    indices = [1, 1, 0, 1]
```

I found the column indices of `C` for which:

```
    i0, i1 = np.where(C[indices] == 1)
```

They are:

```
    i0 = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    i1 = [0, 0, 1, 0]
```

**I want to increment the `A` indices contained in `i0` and `i1` by one and increment the `E` indices contained in `i1` by `delta_E`:**

```
for k, i, j in enumerate(indices[i0], i1):
    A[i,j] += 1
    A[j,i] += 1
    E[i] += delta_E[k]
```

The result is:

Matrix `A`:

```
        array([[0, 4, 1],
               [4, 0, 0],
               [1, 0, 0]])
```

Matrix `E`:

```
        array([4, 7, 0])
```

Is possible to convert the `for` loop above into a matrix expression?

Comment: Have you had a look at numpy?

Comment: Yes, sobek, i try... but you know, numpy have a very large number of methods.

Comment: I'm trying to recreate your calculations, and am hitting some bugs in the iteration.  The enumerate needs a zip, `delta_E[4]` is indexing out of range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [182]: for k,(i,j) in enumerate(zip(indices[i0], i1)):
     ...:     print(k,i,j)
     ...:     
     ...:     
0 1 0
1 1 0
2 0 1
3 0 2
4 1 0
```

While `k` is unique, the `i,j` indices have duplicates.  Replacing the `+=` steps with a whole-array calculation will require using `add.at`, an unbuffered alternative to `A[i] += b`.

```
In [190]: A = np.zeros_like(C)
In [191]: np.add.at(A,(indices[i0],i1),1)
In [192]: np.add.at(A,(i1,indices[i0]),1)
In [193]: A
Out[193]: 
array([[0, 4, 1],
       [4, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0]])
```

For `E`, I can't replicate your value, but I can replicate the loop

```
In [200]: delta_E = np.array([4,2,4,1,0])
In [204]: E = np.zeros(3,int)
In [205]: for k,i in enumerate(indices[i0]):  # your loop
     ...:     E[i] += delta_E[k]
     ...:     
In [206]: E
Out[206]: array([5, 6, 0])
In [207]: E = np.zeros(3,int)
In [208]: np.add.at(E,indices[i0],delta_E)
In [209]: E
Out[209]: array([5, 6, 0])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you make my day!