# Vectorized assignment in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's assume I have a large 2D numpy array, e.g. 1000x1000 elements. I also have two 1D integer arrays of length L, and a float 1D arrray of the same length. If I want to simply assign floats to different positions in the original array according to integer array, I could write:

```
mat = np.zeros((1000,1000))
int1 = np.random.randint(0,999,size=(50000,))
int2 = np.random.randint(0,999,size=(50000,))
f = np.random.rand(50000)
mat[int1,int2] = f
```

But if there were collisions i.e. multiple floats corresponding to single location, all but the last would be overwritten. Is there a way to somehow aggregate all the collisions, e.g. mean or median of all the floats falling at the same location? I would like to take advantage of vectorization and hopefully avoid interpreter loops.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider the `ufunc` `.at` method, e.g. [np.add.at indexing with array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45473896/np-add-at-indexing-with-array)

Comment: If you want the mean and there is no maximum number of times the entry could be updated, you'll need a 3D array to store all the values and then take the mean at the end.

Answer (score 6):

Building on hpaulj's suggestion, here's how to get the mean value in case of collisions:

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.zeros((2,2))
int1 = np.zeros(2, dtype=int)
int2 = np.zeros(2, dtype=int)
f = np.array([0,1])

np.add.at(mat, [int1, int2], f)
n = np.zeros((2,2))
np.add.at(n, [int1, int2], 1)
mat[int1, int2] /= n[int1, int2]
print(mat)

array([[0.5, 0. ],
       [0. , 0. ]])
```

Comment: Very clever and efficient! There is no version for median, though?

Comment: I had a small play with median too but couldn't think of an easy way to get it. (Doesn't mean it doesn't exist :). The main reason is you need to keep a list of all collisions to compute a median, which forces you (I believe) to use python lists which don't integrate well with numpy vectorization...

Answer (score 5):

You can manipulate your data in `pandas` and then assign.

Starting from

```
mat = np.zeros((1000,1000))
a = np.random.randint(0,999,size=(50000,))
b = np.random.randint(0,999,size=(50000,))
c = np.random.rand(50000)
```

You can define a function

```
def get_aggregated_collisions(a,b,c):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'x':a, 'y':b, 'v':c})
    df['coord'] = df[['x','y']].apply(tuple,1)
    d = df.groupby('coord').agg({"v":'mean','x':'first', 'y':'first'}).to_dict('list')
    return d
```

and then

```
d = get_aggregated_collisions(a,b,c)
mat[d['x'], d['y']] = d['v']
```

The whole operation (including generating the matrixes, `np.random` etc) ran quite ok

```
1.05 s ± 30.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

*The idea behind making a `tuple` of coordinates was to have a hashable option to group values by their coordinates. Maybe there is even a smarter way to do this :) always open to suggestions.*

Comment: You don't need to create `tuple`. Just do the grouping based on both `x` and `y` columns.

Comment: @CindyAlmighty Yes, it does ! :) Just change `"mean"` for `"meadian"` or whatever operation you might want.

Comment: @Tai handn't slept in the past 2 days haha:thanks for pointing out. I won't edit not to make your answer redundant. Thanks ;}

Comment: @RafaelC sounds like you have rough days. Feel free to edit your answer to provide users with better information. I would not mind.

Answer (score 3):

My trial based on RafaelC's answer.

First do `groupby` on ["x", "y"], then take `mean` or `median` of each group, and finally reset the index with `reset_index()`.

```
import pandas as np
# setup
mat = np.zeros((1000,1000))
a = np.random.randint(0,999,size=(50000,))
b = np.random.randint(0,999,size=(50000,))
c = np.random.rand(50000)
# Start here
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":a, "y":b, "val":c})
v = df.groupby(["x", "y"]).mean().reset_index()
mat[v["x"], v["y"]] += v["val"]
```

If medians are needed, modify `v` to be

```
v = df.groupby(["x", "y"]).median().reset_index()
```