# Add one to an array at list of indices using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D array, `a`, and another array, `index_list`, that is a list of valid indices for that 2D array. The same index may appear more than once. I want to add one to that 2D array at every index that appears in the list of indices. If an index appears n times, I want to add one n times.

For example, given:

```
a = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
index_list = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[2,2],[2,2]])
```

I want a function to return:

```
[[1,2,2],
 [3,4,5],
 [6,7,10]]
```

How can I do this with just numpy?

Comment: `np.add.at` can handle the duplicate index as you want.

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [np.add.at indexing with array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45473896/np-add-at-indexing-with-array)