# Updating multiple elements in numpy array without loops

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy array such as

```
original_array=np.arange(5)
```

I have another array that stores the value of indices to be updated

```
indices=[0,1,2,1,1]
```

Repetition in elements of `indices` signify that the element is being updated multiple times.

I have also the array that stores the values to be added.

```
updation_values=[0.2,0.2,0.4, 0.5, 0.4]
```

Usually I update the array as

```
for update_value, index in zip(updation_values, indices):
    original_array[index]+=update_value
```

Is there a better way of doing it apart from loops?

```
original_array[indices]+=updation_values
```

does not seem to work as it only does the updation of the last instance of each unique index.

Comment: look up `np.add.at`  - on docs or SO

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45473896/np-add-at-indexing-with-array

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj, I couldn't understand what broadcastability here means when we try to add matrices instead of just numbers.

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions in yours:

1. Why it does not work as expected?
2. How to make it faster?

##### Why it does not work?

You are creating integer ndarray - which means that fractional updates get rounded to the nearest integer and since the updates are <=0.5, there is no apparent change. You can see the ndarray as it is created works for ints:

```
original_array=np.arange(5)#, dtype=np.float)
indices=[0,1,2,1,1]
updation_values=[0.2,0.2,0.4, 0.5, 0.4]
updation_values=[1,1,1,1,1]

for update_value, index in zip(updation_values, indices):
    original_array[index] += update_value

print(original_array)
```

> [1 4 3 3 4]

To ensure you are creating a ndarray with floats you have to use `dtype` optional parameter:

```
original_array=np.arange(5, dtype=np.float)
```

##### How to make it faster?

Generally, you want to use NumPy vectorization. Unfortunately, you have repetition in your `indices` variable so:

```
original_array[indices]+=updation_values
```

will not work.

You can see yourself:

```
print(original_array)
original_array[[0,1,2]] += 10
print(original_aray)
```

results with:

> [1 4 3 3 4]

> [11 14 13  3  4]

and so does:

```
original_array[[0,1,2,0,0]] += 10
```

Comment: I tried even with integer values. It doesn't work.
I made ```updation_values = [1,1,1,1,1]``` and the final result I got was
```original_array=[1,2,3,3,4]``` 
instead of 
```original_array=[1,4,3,3,4]```

Comment: It does for me resulting with: `[1 4 3 3 4]`

Comment: It does. And there is no surprise. If you run it in Jupyter notebook - restart the Python session and restart from scratch with the changes.

Comment: I am comfortable with loops, and I know it works. My question is how to make it faster.  With the second method, ```original_array[indices]+=updation_values``` it does not work. I know why it doesn't work, but how I can do that. 

Please note the difference  in the code blocks of loop and vector.

Comment: Right, didn't address this one. I don't think you can do it this way as you have repeated indices in the `indices` variable.