Adding array of values to target array using array of indices for each value
I have an array of values that I want to add to a target array using an array of indices that specifies where in the target array each value should be added. E.g.:
import numpy as np
values = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
indices = np.array([0,2,2,3,0])
target = np.zeros((4))


# expected output
# magic_func(values, indices, target) --> array([6,0,5,4])

This of course be done by looping through each pair of values and indices:
for i in range(len(values)):
    target[indices[i]] += values[i]

but this becomes slow for long arrays (say, 1000+), which is a problem as I need to do this for millions of pairs of values+indices. Is there a faster way to do this math?

target[indices] += values would work if you didn't have duplicate indices. Can you  first combine the duplicates?

Look at np.add.at if you have duplicate indices.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45474687/901925

np.add.at(target, indices, values)
